# All client outbound SSH is being blocked ... are there any workarounds?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to ssh out of a machine running a client to connect to an SSH remote server. The reason I need this is to port forward/tunnel and get an open connection to an application on the client.

The problem is that it seems that all outbound SSH is being blocked by the proxy / firewall.  I do not have admin access to client machine.  I have control over the remote server machine.  Are there any solutions I can try?

Note:

1. I get no replies when I try to ping from client to external addresses
2. I wonder how I manage to connect to client machine via teamviewer but not via ssh.  How does TeamViewer get through?  Can maybe the same port be used for ssh?

Comment: TeamViewer might use something like [hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching), just like Skype. Not too sure though.

Answer (score 2):

Can you run you ssh server on ports 80 or 443 instead? These are commonly allowed through a firewall/proxy.

Or as you suggest, run it on the teamserver port.

Comment: I can run server on port 80 or 443, but the problem is that client firewall/proxy still blocks the outbound on these ports. I see this as strange since I can browse all websites on client machine without any restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Install `stunnel` on both your server and local machine; configure it to tunnel SSH inside SSL on server's port 443. This will trick *most* proxies into thinking you are connecting to a typical HTTPS website.

Other protocols such as [PingTunnel](http://www.cs.uit.no/~daniels/PingTunnel/) (ICMP Echo) or [Iodine](http://code.kryo.se/iodine/)/[nstx](http://thomer.com/howtos/nstx.html) (DNS) may be a possibility.

As a last resort, if your network MitM's all SSL connections (I've heard that happening), you could install [Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) or [Anyterm](http://anyterm.org/), which work entirely over HTTP[S].

Comment: This sounds promising, never heard of stunnel.  I shall look it up and see if I figure it out.  So 'stunnel' can handle this all on its own or does it still need Putty to create the SSH tunnel?

Comment: stunnel does precisely one thing: tunneling arbitrary TCP connections inside a SSL layer. It does not deal with SSH, you will still need PuTTY for that.